# Launching 32 bit .NET application from 64 bit .NET application performance

Tags: .net, performance, visual-studio

I have a .NET 4.5.2 application (let's call it `AppA`) targeted on AnyCPU. As it handles large amount of data, `Prefer 32-bit` option is off.

I have a helper .NET 4.5.2 application (`AppB`) which is launched from `AppA` on its startup and performs minor configuration tasks.

The question is: Regarding the launch speed on 64 bit systems, should `AppB` have the `Prefer 32-bit` option on, off, or it does not matter at all?

Comment: It could matter, cold start performance of a .NET app is dominated by the disk drive and how well files are cached.  Tends to matter in a .NET app, lots of DLLs.  If bitness matches then at least *some* of the files that the main app needs will be cached.

Comment: Thanks Hans. That's basically what I thought and I was looking for a differing view :) I have no idea how CLR is instantiated, but I would expect there is a 32bit instance and a 64bit instance. Would that mean that invoking the new process could potentially result in a need to start a new CLR instance? If you can suggest some nice reading material, please post it as the answer.